# onclick listener of a button that isnt shown yet

Tags: android, layout, button, onclicklistener, forceclose

I'm having some troubles making a pretty simple thing work. Here is whats going on:

I have an activity that shows layout 1.

Layout 1 has a button to move to layout 2.

And layout 2 moves back to 1.

The activity is working untill the last part. I can open it, move to layout 2 but I can't go back.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = 1;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    if(position == 1 ){
        setContentView(R.layout.p1);        
    }
    if(position == 2 ){
        setContentView(R.layout.p2);        
    }


    final Button p1p21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p1p2);
    final Button p2p11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p2p1);

    p1p21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.p2);

        }

    });

    p2p11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        }

    });

    p2p11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

If I remove this part:

```
    p2p11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        }

    });
```

Then the activity is working. So, I'm guessing the problem is that I cannot make an onclicklistener of a button that isn't visible yet? What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

you should only use setContentView() once.

Comment: that isnt really helping me with my problem.
Activity still crashes without the additional setcontentview. Could you add why? and what else can I do to change layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.p1);

    Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);


    View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.p2);
            Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(listener2);
        }
    });

    View.OnClickListener listener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.p1);
            Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
}
```

This way you initialize the listeners first, and then "inflate" the buttons once you're in a certain layout.

I may be using wrong terms but I'm pretty sure this works.